# Adding properties to virtual files

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell, dataprovider, shell-extensions

I'm developing a explorer data provider based on this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940360.aspx). I already added drag & drop support. Now I want that the files and folders can be ordered by filetyp, size or whatever. The problem seems that the virtual files have only the name property like you can see on the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of shell extension]

How can I add more properties or columns to order the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write a class which implement [`ICategorizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776167.aspx) and to add a mapping into [`IShellFolder2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775055.aspx)`::`[`MapColumnToSCID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775057.aspx) between the index and the `PROPERTYKEY` and also to add a mapping info `IShellFolder2 ::`[`GetDetailsOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775053.aspx) for index and the column name.

That is all :-)